# Does socket.listen(0); pause a thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am thinking of having socket.listen() on a separate thread for my server, does it pause the thread?

I want to have my thread to listen, talk with the client, end client connection, listen again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Listen` method does not block the current thread, it merely sets up the `Socket` to accept new connections.  Methods like `Accept` in synchronous mode will block the thread until a connection is received.

Note: The MSDN documentation for methods on `Socket` are pretty good about listing whether or not they block in the Remarks section.  Example

- [Socket::Accept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.accept.aspx)